# Exclude duplicate lines from two different files and generate new?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, uniq

I have few wordlist files which is based on word per line.

Now, i want to generate new file, that should be:

compared first and second file and putting words from second file, that are not found in first, putting them in third file.

**File_1**

> word1
>
> word2
>
> word3
>
> word4
>
> word5

**File_2**

> word1
>
> word3
>
> word5
>
> word7
>
> word9

I tried few things:

```
cat file.1 file.2 | sort -n | uniq -u | cat > file.3
```

But i get:

**File_3**

> word2
>
> word4
>
> word7
>
> word9

Also i tried:

```
cat file.1 file.2 | sort -n | uniq -d | cat > file.3
```

but again I get:

**File_3**

> word1
>
> word3
>
> word5

I tried also with **ECHO**

```
echo $(cat file.{1,2} | sort -n | uniq -u) > file.3
```

But i get same words, and what is worst it prints all at one line.

The final **File_3** should contain:

> word7
>
> word9

Beacause these words are not found in first file.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: So question can be re-phrased: Remove matching lines from input? `grep` with right flags should do it: pattern should be read from file, separated by newlines, and it should print non-matching instead of matching files. It has flags to do just this I believe, so re-read the man page.

Comment: Maybe you forgot a few `cat`s there? Seriously, though; avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is not big you can basically cat first file twice:

```
cat file.1 file.1 file.2 | sort -n | uniq -u | cat > file.3
```

but this is expensive for big files.

or using grep you can achieve this (thanks to @tripleee):

```
grep -F -x -v -f file.1 file.2 > file.3
```

Comment: The `grep` will remove too much if `file.1` contains partial matches, and either too little or too much if stuff in `file.1` contain characters which do not match themselves and only themselves under a regex interpretation. Adding `-F -x` fixes both issues.

Comment: files are basically 5 to 15GB in size :D

Comment: The `sort` assumes that the files do not already contain any duplicates (and uses [two cats too many](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
grep -F -x -v -f file.1 file.2 >file.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file_1 file_2 > file_3
$ cat file_3
word7
word9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [comm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) program to do this:

```
comm -13 <(sort file_1) <(sort file_2)
```